# Apache Artemis Prometheus metrics plugin HTTP endpoint responds "404 - Not found"

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using Apache Artemis v2.31.0, and I'm facing an issue with the [Prometheus metrics plugin](https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). The plugin gets initialized during startup, however it returns "404- Not found" for metrics endpoint (`curl -v http://broker:9050/metrics/`).

I tried restarting the Artemis broker instance and it provides the metrics data, but at most times the metrics endpoint returns "404 - Not found".

Comment: https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin

Comment: Using the above plugin to integrate with Prometheus for scraping metrics.

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: not sure how this can be reproduced, but my observation & assumption  is that this started happening after more number(3000) of address and queues got created. And it is noticed right after broker instance restart.